How to aggregate repeated elements on a list of dictionaries as a nested dictionary?
How can I aggregate a list of dictionaries with repeated elements into a nested dictionary as follows?
Original list:
list_dict = [{'id': 1, 'table': 8, 'category': 'fruit', 'product': 'banana', 'price': 4, 'qty': 5}, 
             {'id': 1, 'table': 8, 'category': 'fruit', 'product': 'apple', 'price': 5, 'qty': 9}, 
             {'id': 1, 'table': 8, 'category': 'fruit', 'product': 'orange', 'price': 6, 'qty': 3}, 
             {'id': 2, 'table': 5, 'category': 'vegetable', 'product': 'carrot', 'price': 4, 'qty': 5}, 
             {'id': 2, 'table': 5, 'category': 'vegetable', 'product': 'potato', 'price': 2, 'qty': 3}]

Expected result:
list_dict = 
[{'id': 1, 'table': 8, 'category': 'fruit', 'products': [{'product': 'banana', 'price': 4, 'qty': 5},
                                                         {'product': 'apple', 'price': 5, 'qty': 9},
                                                         {'product': 'orange', 'price': 6, 'qty': 3}]},
{'id': 2, 'table': 5, 'category': 'vegetable', 'products': [{'product': 'carrot', 'price': 4, 'qty': 5}, 
                                                            {'product': 'potato', 'price': 2, 'qty': 3}]}]

I have been trying to achieve it with itertools.groupby but I was not able to get it properly.

You don't need itertools.groupby, just group your items with help of dictionary:
out = {}
for d in list_dict:
    out.setdefault((d["id"], d["table"], d["category"]), []).append(
        {"product": d["product"], "price": d["price"], "qty": d["qty"]}
    )

out = [
    {"id": id_, "table": table, "category": category, "products": v}
    for (id_, table, category), v in out.items()
]
print(out)

Prints:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "table": 8,
        "category": "fruit",
        "products": [
            {"product": "banana", "price": 4, "qty": 5},
            {"product": "apple", "price": 5, "qty": 9},
            {"product": "orange", "price": 6, "qty": 3},
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "table": 5,
        "category": "vegetable",
        "products": [
            {"product": "carrot", "price": 4, "qty": 5},
            {"product": "potato", "price": 2, "qty": 3},
        ],
    },
]


from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

list_dict = [{'id': 1, 'table': 8, 'category': 'fruit', 'product': 'banana', 'price': 4, 'qty': 5}, 
             {'id': 1, 'table': 8, 'category': 'fruit', 'product': 'apple', 'price': 5, 'qty': 9}, 
             {'id': 1, 'table': 8, 'category': 'fruit', 'product': 'orange', 'price': 6, 'qty': 3}, 
             {'id': 2, 'table': 5, 'category': 'vegetable', 'product': 'carrot', 'price': 4, 'qty': 5}, 
             {'id': 2, 'table': 5, 'category': 'vegetable', 'product': 'potato', 'price': 2, 'qty': 3}]

nested_dict = defaultdict(dict)

for item in list_dict:
    id_key = item['id'], item['table'], item['category']
    if id_key not in nested_dict:
        nested_dict[id_key] = {'id': item['id'], 'table': item['table'], 'category': item['category'], 'items': []}
    nested_dict[id_key]['items'].append({'product': item['product'], 'price': item['price'], 'qty': item['qty']})

pprint(list(nested_dict.values()))

Result:
[{'category': 'fruit',
  'id': 1,
  'items': [{'price': 4, 'product': 'banana', 'qty': 5},
            {'price': 5, 'product': 'apple', 'qty': 9},
            {'price': 6, 'product': 'orange', 'qty': 3}],
  'table': 8},
 {'category': 'vegetable',
  'id': 2,
  'items': [{'price': 4, 'product': 'carrot', 'qty': 5},
            {'price': 2, 'product': 'potato', 'qty': 3}],
  'table': 5}]

but I think Pandas is better choice for this kind of problems.

[
  {'id': k[0], 'table': k[1], 'category': next(d)['category'], 'products':list({'product': item['product'], 'price': item['price'], 'qty': item['qty'] }for item in d)} for k, d in groupby(list_dict, key=lambda x: (x['id'], x['table']))
]

you can run it here
